# How do I set additionalProperties: false using nestjs/swagger

Tags: openapi, nestjs-swagger

The Schema was implemented using @ApiBody({type:CreateUserInput})
I need need to be able to prevent it from accepting additional properties according OPENAAPI specification by setting additionalPropeerties:false but i dont know how to implement it.

````json
"schemas": {
      "CreateUserInput": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "for firstname",
            "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,10}$",
            "maxLength": 50,
            "minLength": 10
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "for email",
            "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,10}$",
            "maxLength": 50,
            "minLength": 10
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "for email",
            "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,10}$",
            "maxLength": 50,
            "minLength": 10
          },
          "password": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 10,
            "maxLength": 50,
            "description": "for email",
            "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,10}$"
          }
        },
        "required": ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "password"]
      },```
````